# Node.js loading empty css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

pretty new to node.js, and I was wondering if anything can help me with this small css and image bug I have. Ive only posted the main parts of my html and .js just to keep it clean. Anyways my css and image arent loading. Ive tried pratically everything but cant figure it. Everything works my form, the server, everything but the css and image. Any help would be great!

file structure

```
webDemo
node_modules
public
   css
     indexCss.css
   images
      powerbyfhirlogo.JPG
index.html
package.json
server.js
```

main part of my node file.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var formidable = require("formidable");
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var request = require("request");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
    displayForm(res);
}
else if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {

    processFormFieldsIndividual(req, res);
  }
});

function displayForm(res) {


    fs.readFile('index.html', function (err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'Content-Length': data.length
    });

    res.write(data);
    res.end();
});
}

server.listen(63342);
console.log("server listening on 63342");
```

beginning of my html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>MI FHIR Demo Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/indexCss.css" />

</head>
 <body>
<div class=container1>
    <img src= "public/images/powerbyfhirlogo.JPG" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre">
    <h1>MI FHIR Demo Form</h1>
</div>
<hr/>

<div class=container2>
    <form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Edit**
**solution**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var server = express();

var port = process.env.port || 63342;

// Setup Views & View Engine
server.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
server.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
server.set('view engine', 'html');


// Define ./public as static
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//All POST's use processFormFieldsIndividual
server.post('*', processFormFieldsIndividual);

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('listening on port ' + port);
});
```

new file structure

```
webDemo
   node_modules
   public
      css
        indexCss.css
      images
         powerbyfhirlogo.JPG
      index.html
   package.json
   server.js
```

Comment: Try `css/indexCss.css`

Comment: @VikramTiwari In the html? ive done that still doesnt work, plus it gives me a cannot resolve directory css/file error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're utilizing two different servers within your server file, `app` and `server`. That is really where you're going wrong. You can't mix and match two different servers and expect one to work for the other and vice versa.

If you're going to use express then you don't need `http.createServer()` since express is a Node Core http server.

Additionally, you don't want to keep redeclaring your static files for every single `GET` request, its not necessary.

Fundamentally this is what you need

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var server = express();

var port = process.env.port || 63342;

// Setup Views & View Engine
server.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
server.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
server.set('view engine', 'html');


// Define ./public as static
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//All GET's render index.html
server.get('*', function(req, res) {
    return res.render('index');
});  

//All POST's use processFormFieldsIndividual
server.post('*', processFormFieldsIndividual);

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('listening on port ' + port);
});
```

#### EDIT

To do away with `res.sendFile()` which is unnecessary, I've incorporated the use of a `view engine` utilizing [`ejs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs). In order to use this you'll need to install `ejs` as dependency through `npm`.

`npm i --save ejs`

Additionally, you'll need to place your `index.html` in a new directory in your project folder called `views`. This is allows you to take advantage of `res.render` which eliminates the usage of `res.sendFile()`. Your new directory structure will look like the one below.

```
webDemo
node_modules
public
   css
     indexCss.css
   images
      powerbyfhirlogo.JPG
views
   index.html
package.json
server.js
```

Comment: TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
   at ServerResponse.sendFile (..express\lib\response.js:403:11)
   at displayForm (..webDemo\server.js:48:9)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] ..express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (..\webDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (..express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (..express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at ...express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
   at param (..webDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:349:14)

Comment: Then do `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')`

Comment: function displayForm(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), function(err) {
        if (err)
            return res.status(err.status).end();
        return;
    });
 }

Comment: Like that? if i do that it loads the page but the css and image still dont work.

Comment: @Samkh see my edit to remove the use of `res.sendFile()` in favor of a view engine and `res.render()` setup. Just make sure you install `ejs` from npm. `npm i --save ejs`.

Comment: should i add var app = express(); ?

Comment: @Samkh Sorry that was a typo, it should be `server`, updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113782/discussion-between-sam-kh-and-peteb).

Comment: listening on port 63342
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::63342
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1231:14)
    at listen (net.js:1267:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1363:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (.\webDemo\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:617:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.\webDemo\server.js:131:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

Comment: its not liking the server.listen()

Comment: Thats because you're already listening somewhere else. You need to kill those

Comment: just worked on it again, and with youre fixes all i needed to do was put my index.html file in the public folder with out the views folder for some reason. Thank you @peteb